# make div 100% of browser height depending on length of content

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have 2 divs, a navigation and a main content in a bootstrap grid system. The length of either can vary depending on amount of content. I need them both styled to fill 100% of the browser window IF neither has the content to reach the bottom naturally. But if at least one of the divs has more content than the length of the browser window, I need to be able to scroll down the page with the styles of both divs remaining in tact and both have a height of the longer of the 2 divs.

I'm currently using a javascript resize function which seems to work but not in the case where neither div is long enough to fill the height of the browser window. Any suggestions?

**HTML**

```
<div class="row">
    <div id="nav" class="col-xs-2">
        Variable Height Navigation
    </div>
    <div id="main" class="col-xs-10">
        Variable Height Content
    </div>
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
function resize() {
    var h = (document.height !== undefined) ? document.height : document.body.offsetHeight;                                                           
    document.getElementById("nav").style.height = h + "px";
}

resize();
window.onresize = function () {
    resize();
};
```

Answer (score 1):

I am trying to understand you question, and if I'm correct what you are looking for is:

- Both divs need to be equally high
- They need be at least the height of the screen
- They need to take the height of the highest div

So let's try to achieve this goal as simply as possible:

```js
var main = document.getElementById('main');
var nav  = document.getElementById('nav');

function resize(){
    var highest;
    // Set the divs back to autosize, so we can measure their content height correctly.
    main.style.height = 'auto';
    nav.style.height  = 'auto';
    // Find the highest div and store its height.
    highest = main.clientHeight > nav.clientHeight
        ? main.clientHeight
        : nav.clientHeight;
    // Check if the highest value is the div or the window.
    highest = highest > window.innerHeight
        ? highest
        : window.innerHeight;
    // Assign the newly found value
    main.style.height = highest + 'px';
    nav.style.height  = highest + 'px';
}
  
resize();
// Also, you don't need to wrap it in a function.
window.resize = resize;
// However, better would be:
window.addEventListener('resize', resize, false);
```

```css
#main, #nav {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
#main { background: red; }
#nav { background: green; }
```

```html
<div id="main"></div>
<div id="nav"></div>
```

Now, If you aren't bothered with the actual sameness in heiught of both divs but just want them to at least be one screenful, you should consider using CSS:

```
html, body { height: 100%; }
#nav, #main { min-height: 100%; }
```

I think that is the better solution (no Javascript!) and sort-of does what you want, bar the fact that you won't have to equally high `div` elements. However, you would barely notice it as each will at least fill the page.

Comment: Thanks, the problem with min height 100% is that if one of the divs is longer than the length of the screen, the shorter one's height is cut off at the point of scroll.

Comment: It shouldn't actually be an issue. Both with minwidth 100% should make them at least the height of their wrappers. Your wrapper needs a minheight of 200% in that case though.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using viewport height:

For example:

```
#nav {
  min-height: 100vh;
}

#main {
  min-height: 100vh;
}
```

See [Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/lgpPBtlIF5).

This will also remove the need for JavaScript.